# Low text graphics after fglrx update

Tags: 14.04, ati, fglrx

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and after some software updates this morning I just got a black screen after login.

This is my graphic card:

```
lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Juniper XT [Radeon HD 5770]
```

So I installed from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

and now I'm able to login, but my text is very (grainy/ginned/hulled/unshelled? sorry I don't know the word) and sometimes violet, like I'm using some low quality JPG compression:

[image] [image]

I hope you can see it from these images. Any suggestion about how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the  video drivers with the package `xserver-xorg-video-all`.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic xserver-xorg-video-all libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
```

Comment: `code` libgl1-mesa-dri is already the newest version.
libgl1-mesa-glx is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-core is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-all is already the newest version.
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.`code`

Comment: Try to remove that video drivers and then re-install it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm quite newbie with drivers, how can I do it?

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`

Comment: I've done it, no output in terminal. After restart it's still the same.

Comment: Do first: `cd /usr/share/ati
sudo sh ./fglrx-uninstall.sh` and then the command what I told above, then: `sudo reboot`

Comment: `/usr/share/ati$ ls` ----->

`amdcccle  KernelVersionList.txt  lib64`

;no sh scripts

Comment: Try this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Comment: Directly from AMD's website or via the Ubuntu repositories? Which one is better?